# Merge 2 arrays with Odd and Even numbers and display as Natural Numbers with TASK Operation

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, c#-8.0

Consider we have 2 asynchronous methods

```cs
public async Task<int[]> GetOddNumbers() 
{
  return new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
}
```

```cs
public async Task<int[]> GetEvenNumbers()
{
  return new int[] { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 }; 
}
```

I wanted to combined both the array and display as `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`.

How can we achieve this through TAP (Task based Asynchronous Pattern) in C#?
Please help with valuable suggestion.

Comment: Why you want to do this simple operation using TAP? What is asynchronous about it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Why are these methods async? They return value synchronously. If it is just a simplified example then you should give it a try to use `Zip`, just like this:  `var numbers = (await GetOddNumbers()).Zip(await GetEvenNumbers());`

Comment: Sorry, I've missed to flatten it. You should add this at the end of the linq expression: `.SelectMany((f) => new int[] {f.First, f.Second})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current implementation does not require any asynchronous code.

I suppose that it is just a simplified example, so I'll treat them as async methods.

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var odds = await GetOddNumbers();
    var evens = await GetEvenNumbers();
    var numbers = (odds).Zip(evens)
      .SelectMany(tuple => new [] { tuple.First, tuple.Second });

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

1. We retrieve both collections.
2. We combine (`Zip`) one element from the `odds` to another element in the `evens`. So, we would end up with the following structure (an array of tuples):

```cs
[
  (1,2),
  (3,4),
  (5,6),
  (7,8),
  (9,10),
]
```

3. In order to flatten this we need to call the `SelectMany`. You can access the left item via the `First` property and the right item via the `Second` property.
   3.1) If you would call only just `Select` not `SelectMany` then you would end up with an array of arrays.

```cs
[
  [1,2],
  [3,4],
  [5,6],
  [7,8],
  [9,10],
]
```

3.2) But with `SelectMany` we flatten the array of arrays to a simple array.

```cs
[
  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
]
```

---

**UPDATE**: A new requirement has been added (as a comment) by the OP that the data should be retrieved one-by-one and asynchronously.

In order to satisfy this we need to make use of the the `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`. This gives us ability to provide one data at a time when it is available.

#### Provider side

So instead of returning a `Task<int[]>` we have to return with an `IAsyncEnumerable<int>`. The `GetOddNumbers` and `GetEvenNumbers` could be rewritten like this:

```cs
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetOddNumbers()
{
    var odds = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
    foreach (var odd in odds)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); //Whatever async method call
        yield return odd;
    }
}
```

```cs
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetEvenNumbers()
{
    var evens = new int[] { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };
    foreach (var even in evens)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); //Whatever async method call
        yield return even;
    }
}
```

#### Consumer side

We can take advantage of the new `await foreach` keyword of C# 8. There is no built-in `Zip` function for IAsyncEnumerable, so we need to use a custom one, like this: [async-enumerable-dotnet](https://github.com/akarnokd/async-enumerable-dotnet)

With these in hand the `Main` method would look like this:

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var toBeIterated = async_enumerable_dotnet.AsyncEnumerable.Zip(z => z, GetOddNumbers(), GetEvenNumbers());
    await foreach (int[] oddEvenPair in toBeIterated)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(oddEvenPair[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(oddEvenPair[1]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

It will print out one pair of the data at a time and then it waits one sec between the next pair.

```
{1 sec wait}
1
2
{1 sec wait}
3
4
{1 sec wait}
5
6
{1 sec wait}
7
8
{1 sec wait}
9
10
Finished
```

Comment: Thanks. This will work. But my intention is more into merging 2 tasks, such that, First Value of Task1 is retrieved, then first value of Task2, then second value of task1 and then second value of task2 and so on..

I hope there should be some possibility to achieve this using TAP.

The Question is just a sample data. But in realtime, the values will be retrieved asynchronously.

Comment: @vinothkarunanithy Yep, I'm absolutely got it what you want. I will update my answer according to these new requirements in a few minutes.

Comment: @vinothkarunanithy I've updated my answer, please check it.